# How to programatically detect if a minor mode is global or local?

Tags: minor-mode

Is there a way to programatically detect (in Elisp) if a minor mode is a global minor mode or a local minor mode?

For instance I'd like to be able to detect that `show-paren-mode` is a global minor mode and that [smart-dash-mode](http://malsyned.net/smart-dash.html) is a local minor mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information isn't stored, unfortunately.

You *can* check whether the mode variable `show-paren-mode` is global or buffer-local:

```el
(local-variable-if-set-p 'show-paren-mode)
```

That's not a guarantee (there's nothing stopping you giving a global mode a buffer-local value), but it's a reasonable heuristic.

You might deal with that issue with:

```el
(with-temp-buffer
  (local-variable-if-set-p 'show-paren-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume it could also be checked with local-variable-p.  Both of these are implemented in C and have an optional BUFFER argument, at least back to Emacs 26.3, not sure before.

Comment: If you're only dealing with buffers where the mode is *enabled*, then `local-variable-p` would be as good, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Phils' answer, I noted that:

- When checking if a minor-mode is local or global inside a function invoked for a major-mode by a hook, the code must **first** check if the mode variable is bound before doing the check with either `local-variable-if-set-p` or `local-variable-p`.  Otherwise if the minor-mode is auto-loaded and not yet loaded, then both `local-variable-if-set-p` and `local-variable-p` return nil even if the minor-mode is a local minor-mode.

I wanted to verify the validity of automatic minor-mode activation done by a hook for major-mode and generate a warning if a global minor-mode was activated via a hook meant to activate only local minor-modes (and vice-versa).  If the minor-mode is auto-loaded and a major-mode is activated early (like when you start Emacs and open a file in that major mode right away) then the check would fail and warning generation was not reliable.

Ideally the code would also detect that the variable is auto-loaded, load the file and check again.  But that's out of the scope of the current question.